# Two-dimensional vs. One-dimensional dictionary efficiency in Python

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, nested, tuples

What is more efficient in terms of memory and speed between

`d[(first,second)]`

and

`d[first][second]`,

where `d` is a dictionary of either tuples or dictionaries?

Comment: The first is *one* dictionary, the second *two*. Memorywise two dictionaries will likely consume more memory - but then again, it will all depend on your apps data profile.

Comment: I think the answer here is it's pretty much negligible. The real question here should be: *what is more usable for readers/writers of code using it?*.

Comment: miku's statement "The first [statement] is *one* dictionary, the second [statement] *two*." is not exactly correct. The second statement `d[a][b]` is actually N+1 dictionaries, where N is the number of unique values of `a`.

Comment: performance is paramount here, since the need for a faster execution greatly outweighs the need for code quality/readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some very basic test data that indicates that for a very contrived example(storing 'a' a million times using numbers as keys) using 2 dictionaries is significantly faster.

```
$ python -m timeit 'd = {i:{j:"a" for j in range(1000)} for i in range(1000)};a = [d[i][j] for j in range(1000) for i in range(1000)];'
10 loops, best of 3: 316 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'd = {(i, j):"a" for j in range(1000) for i in range(1000)};a = [d[i, j] for j in range(1000) for i in range(1000)];'
10 loops, best of 3: 970 msec per loop
```

Of course, these tests do not necessarily mean anything depending on what you are trying to do.  Determine what you'll be storing, and then test.

A little more data:

```
$ python -m timeit 'a = [(hash(i), hash(j)) for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)]'
10 loops, best of 3: 304 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'a = [hash((i, j)) for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)]'
10 loops, best of 3: 172 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'd = {i:{j:"a" for j in range(1000)} for i in range(1000)}'
10 loops, best of 3: 101 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'd = {(i, j):"a" for j in range(1000) for i in range(1000)}'
10 loops, best of 3: 645 msec per loop
```

Once again this is clearly *not* indicative of real world use, but it seems to me like the cost of building a dictionary with tuples like that is *huge* and that's where the dictionary in a dictionary wins out.  This surprises me, I was expecting completely different results.  I'll have to try a few more things when I have time.

Comment: Interesting. My guess would be that the difference is the increased time it takes to hash a `tuple`?

Comment: @agf posted some more data, I'm really not sure why the difference is so extreme.  It's much more expensive to build the dict using tuples, but hashing tuples is actually *faster?*  I'm using really crude methods so I might be reading too far into the data but I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: I wonder if looping over the values individually when you build the two dimensional dictionary allows you to cache a lot more.  That seems like a potential explanation.

Comment: "Note that there is a fast-path for dicts that (in practice) only deal with str keys; this doesn't affect the algorithmic complexity, but it can significantly affect the constant factors: how quickly a typical program finishes." [Source](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) might also affect this.

Answer (score 1):

A little surprisingly, the dictionary of dictionaries is faster than the tuple in both CPython 2.7 and Pypy 1.8.

I didn't check on space, but you can do that with ps.

Comment: Dictionaries are hash tables, right? So of course they're fast, but they take up a lot of space.

Comment: What is faster?  Intuitively, I expect insertions on the dictionary of dictionaries to be slower since you often have to initialize a new dictionary (if you are using a new first key).  However, I'd expect accesses to be faster since there will be an order of magnitude fewer collisions.  Please provide code so we can see what you're actually benchmarking.